# plsql: execute query: invalid identifier

Tags: dynamic, plsql, execute, rowtype

Why can't I execute the `stmt` query?

It shows `tabb` is invalid identifier.

```
  TYPE tab_row IS TABLE OF tab_name%ROWTYPE;
  tabb tab_row;
  TYPE cur_ref Is Ref Cursor;
  c           cur_ref;
  stmt_string Varchar2(1000);
  stmt Varchar2(1000);
Begin
   stmt_string := 'Select * from ' || tab1 || ' mft 
             Where mft.mfmt_id IS NOT NULL 
             and mft.MFMT_FLAG IS NULL';
  Open c For stmt_string;
  Fetch c bulk collect into tabb;
  Close c;
 stmt:= 'Update '|| tab || ' m 
    Set m.mfmt_mat_bnr = tabb(i).mfmt_mat_bnr, 
    m.mfmt_mat_type = tabb(i).mfmt_mat_type,
    m.mfmt_be_seg = tabb(i).mfmt_be_seg
    Where m.mfmt_id = tabb(i).mfmt_id';

  For i in 1..tabb.count loop    
    Execute Immediate stmt;
  End loop;
 End;
```

Comment: What it is tabb? Where is it being declared?

Comment: tabb is the collection table

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen where is `tabb` being declared. As you mentioned in your comment, it is a collection.

From your code I can understand you are looping through the values of this collection. This means these values are *variables* i.e. changing values every iteration. Therefore, you need to use them as such.

You current dynamic statement, this values are static string. This `Set m.mfmt_mat_bnr = tabb(i).mfmt_mat_bnr,` will result in the same string every iteration. Hence, you need to change that to `Set m.mfmt_mat_bnr = '|| tabb(i).mfmt_mat_bnr||', ...etc`

I can rewrite your code as follows:

```
TYPE tab_row IS TABLE OF tab_name%ROWTYPE;
tabb tab_row;
TYPE cur_ref Is Ref Cursor;
c           cur_ref;
stmt_string Varchar2(1000);
stmt Varchar2(1000);
Begin
stmt_string := 'Select * from ' || tab1 || ' mft 
            Where mft.mfmt_id IS NOT NULL 
            and mft.MFMT_FLAG IS NULL';
Open c For stmt_string;
Fetch c bulk collect into tabb;
Close c;
stmt:= 'Update '|| tab || ' m 
Set m.mfmt_mat_bnr = '||tabb(i).mfmt_mat_bnr||', 
m.mfmt_mat_type = '||tabb(i).mfmt_mat_type||',
m.mfmt_be_seg = '||tabb(i).mfmt_be_seg||'
Where m.mfmt_id = '||tabb(i).mfmt_id;

 For i in 1..tabb.count loop    
    Execute Immediate stmt;
  End loop;
 End;
```

Since this code is not tested, one thing I strongly recommend to confirm first. Is that `tabb` is correctly declared within the scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in your loop where you execute your statement, maybe try using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE .. USING` statement?

The syntax is:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <SQL Command>
        [INTO <variable list>]
        [USING <bind variable list>];
```

You might try the code below, then:

```
    DECLARE
        -- your tab1 may contain some insignificant columns with values (especially huge ones e.g. CLOB/BLOB)
        -- which will extremely affect procedure's efficiency, so it's a better practice to select only those values that we need
        TYPE t_tab_rec  IS RECORD (
            mfmt_mat_bnr                tab_name.mfmt_mat_bnr%TYPE
            ,mfmt_mat_type              tab_name.mfmt_mat_type%TYPE
            ,mfmt_be_seg                tab_name.mfmt_be_seg%TYPE
            ,mfmt_id                    tab_name.mfmt_id%TYPE
        );

        TYPE t_tab_arr IS TABLE OF t_tab_rec;
        tabb            t_tab_arr := NEW t_tab_arr();
        TYPE ref_cur IS REF CURSOR RETURN t_tab_rec;    -- to assure cursor is returning t_tab_rec type records
        c               cur_ref;
        stmt_select     VARCHAR2(1000);
        stmt_upadte     VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN

        stmt_select := 
            'SELECT
                mft.mfmt_mat_bnr
                ,mft.mfmt_mat_type
                ,mft.mfmt_be_seg
                ,mft.mfmt_id
            FROM
                '||tab1||' mft
            WHERE
                mft.mfmt_id IS NOT NULL
                AND mft.mfmt_flag IS NOT NULL';

        OPEN c FOR stmt_select;
        FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO tabb;
        CLOSE c;

        stmt_upadte := 
            'UPDATE '||tab||'
            SET mfmt_mat_bnr = :p_mfmt_mat_bnr
                ,mfmt_mat_type = :p_mfmt_mat_type
                ,mfmt_be_seg = :p_mfmt_be_seg
            WHERE
                mfmt_id = :p_mfmt_id';

        FOR idx IN tabb.FIRST .. tabb.LAST
        LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_update USING tabb(idx).mfmt_mat_bnr, tabb(idx).mfmt_mat_type, tabb(idx).mfmt_be_seg, tabb(idx).mfmt_id;
        END LOOP;

    END;
    /
```